# error message with exception in cross product

Tags: python, class, exception, vector, product

I'm trying to define a class Vector, in a way the cross-product of two vectors `v1 and v2` results in a ***perpendicular unit vector `v3`***, while such a product is zero, then it should turn back an exception message. I've set the code as follows:

```
  def __init__(self, x, y, z):   
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.z = z

  def __repr__(self): 
    return "Vector(" + str(self.x) + ", " + str(self.y) + ", " + str(self.z) + ")"
  
  def cross(self, V):  
    return Vector(self.y * V.z - self.z * V.y,self.z * V.x - self.x * V.z,self.x * V.y - self.y * V.x)

  def find_axis(v,w):
        x = v.cross(w)
        print(type(x))
        if x==Vector(0,0,0):
            return "error"
    #raise Exception(" (ValueError)")return x
```

But when trying to run the product between vectors, which cross product would be supposed to be different from zero, like the following example:

```
v = Vector(1, 2, 3)
w = Vector(1, 2, 3)
```

And I get excalty:

```
v.cross(w)
Vector(0, 0, 0)
```

I cannot figure out which the error is, since in this case the code is supposed to return an error message. Can anyone please know what is up?

A second way I tried was

```
class Vector:

  def __init__(self, x, y, z):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.z = z

  def __repr__(self): 
    return "Vector(" + str(self.x) + ", " + str(self.y) + ", " + str(self.z) + ")"
        
  def cross(self, V):  
    return Vector(self.y * V.z - self.z * V.y,self.z * V.x - self.x * V.z,self.x * V.y - self.y * V.x)

  def __eq__(self, V):
        if self.x == V.x and self.y == V.y and self.z == V.z: 
            raise ValueError("negative x")
```

but I got the same problem

Comment: Your code doesn't call `find_axis` which is where the error would be raised/printed? You probably need to also define a `__eq__` method for comparing two different instances for equality

Comment: Actually, I tried also to enter an if statement un ììder the cross product definition like this   `def cross(self, V):  
    return Vector(self.y * V.z - self.z * V.y,self.z * V.x - self.x * V.z,self.x * V.y - self.y * V.x)
  if Vector(self.y * V.z - self.z * V.y,self.z * V.x - self.x * V.z,self.x * V.y - self.y * V.x) == 0:
        return "error"`

Comment: But I had the same problem

Comment: I will try and let know

Comment: It's incredibly hard to read code in a comment with the lack of indentation, please add it to the question if you feel it's relevant. From what I understand of it though, why would the new vector ever equal `0`?

Comment: I have entered it into the question

Comment: Your `__eq__` method could simply be `return self.x == V.x and self.y == V.y and self.z == V.z`, return true if all fields are equal?

Comment: I tried now, this way (if that means the same)....but it does not work

Comment: @Iain Shelvington you could look at the updated version of the code, by following your suggestion. It returns the cross product value not the exception message

Comment: But anyway the exception should be returned when cross product is zero, so I do not know if that is the way to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this just required to invert in the exact order the if statement unde cross definition:

```
class Vector:

  def __init__(self, x, y, z):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.z = z

  def __repr__(self): 
    return "Vector(" + str(self.x) + ", " + str(self.y) + ", " + str(self.z) + ")"
        
  def cross(self, V):
    if self.x == V.x and self.y == V.y and self.z == V.z: 
        raise ValueError("The vector is parallel and not perpendicular")
    else:    
        return Vector(self.y * V.z - self.z * V.y, self.z * V.x - self.x * V.z,self.x * V.y - self.y * V.x)
```

*#1st case*

```
v = Vector(1, 2, 3)
w = Vector(9, 2, 3)

print(v.cross(w))
```

*#2nd Case*

```
v = Vector(1, 2, 3)
w = Vector(1, 2, 3)

print(v.cross(w))
```